# Use regex to match a youtube playlist url, and not a song that is part of a playlist

Tags: javascript, regex, string

Basically, I'm trying to write a regex that matches urls like this:

`https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLBOh8f9FoHHjOz0vGrD20WcTtJar-LOrw`

But not urls like this:

`https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4jduuQh-Uho&list=PLBOh8f9FoHHjOz0vGrD20WcTtJar-LOrw&index=3`

I tried to write one that matches if there is a `list=` and no `v=` but it matches both urls.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: You need to mention the code which did you try

Comment: Try getting some results using this: https://regexr.com/ Then update your post again if it's not complete by then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to do this using the regex string `test` function, with the following regex pattern:

```
^(?!.*\?.*\bv=)https:\/\/www\.youtube\.com\/.*\?.*\blist=.*$
```

```js
// case one, a failing url with a v= query parameter
var url1 = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4jduuQh-Uho&list=PLBOh8f9FoHHjOz0vGrD20WcTtJar-LOrw&index=3';
console.log(/^(?!.*\?.*\bv=)https:\/\/www\.youtube\.com\/.*\?.*\blist=.*$/.test(url2));

// case two, a passing URL with list= and no v=
var url2 = 'https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLBOh8f9FoHHjOz0vGrD20WcTtJar-LOrw';
console.log(/^(?!.*\?.*\bv=)https:\/\/www\.youtube\.com\/.*\?.*\blist=.*$/.test(url2));
```

The pattern uses a negative lookahead to rule out any URL which has a `v=` query parameter.  Then, it matches a URL which does have a `list=` query parameter.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:youtu\.be\/|(?:www\.|m\.)?youtube\.com\/(?:playlist|list|embed)(?:\.php)?(?:\?.*list=|\/))([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can extract video url from give url string via regex

```
^.*(youtu.be\/|list=)([^#\&\?]*).*
```

Regex sample :https://regex101.com/r/CWYDyf/1

Comment: It matches both urls, I need it to match only urls like the first one.

Answer (score 0):

i think the right answer is use wildcard *, the regex right may be '.*\?list=.*'

Answer (score 0):

What about matching 'playlist' instead of 'list'?
It is only in one of these links.

Or you can match the urls without word 'watch' this way:

```
(^https:(?:(?<!watch).)*?$)
```

(replace ^ with starting character sequence and $ with ending character sequence)
if these characters are ", then you may do something like that:

```
("https:(?:(?<!watch)[^"])*?")
```

where [^"] will accept any character except "